# Preloader personalizado en video

Tags: jquery

¿Cómo puedo poner un preloader personalizado en un video?, antes de que aparezca el boton de reproducir. Y que desaparezca justo cuando cargue completamente el vídeo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver en este articulo lo que buscas.

http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/web-development/build-an-html5-video-preloader/